# MySQL table indexes change location

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, schema

Is it possible to move the MySQL Table indexes to another location rather than "**datadir**" ? for example a ssd drive or memory partition ?

Comment: What does the documentation say?  Have you tried doing a test in a test database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot move just indexes to another location. You have to move both data and indexes.

When you use [**innodb_file_per_table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), this will create a file with the extension `.ibd`.

For example, if you have an InnoDB table as follows

- datadir `/var/lib/mysql`
- database `mydb`
- table `mytable`

The physical files are the following

- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytables.frm`
- `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytables.ibd`

The file `/var/lib/mysql/mydb/mytables.ibd` contains both data and index pages for `mydb.mytable`.

If you have another disk (says an SSD or HDD) and you want the `.ibd` file to be moved over there, you may have to use the `DATA DIRECTORY` directive for the `CREATE TABLE` command.

Here is what the [MySQL Documentation for `CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) says on this:

> DATA DIRECTORY, INDEX DIRECTORY
>
> For InnoDB, the DATA DIRECTORY='directory' option allows you to create
>   new InnoDB file-per-table tablespaces in a location outside the MySQL
>   data directory. Within the directory that you specify, MySQL creates a
>   subdirectory corresponding to the database name, and within that a
>   .ibd file for the new table. To use the DATA DIRECTORYoption with
>   InnoDB tables, the innodb_file_per_table configuration option must be
>   enabled. The directory must be the full path name to the directory,
>   not a relative path. See Section 14.5.4, “Specifying the Location of a
>   Tablespace” for additional information.

Just a heads up on this: `INDEX DIRECTORY` only applies to MyISAM not InnoDB.
Suppose you have an SSD mounted on `/innodb_data` and you ran `chown -R mysql:mysql /innodb_data`

Here is how you can move `mydb.mytable` (by essentially copying)

```
CREATE TABLE LIKE mydb.mytable_new DATA DIRECTORY '/innodb_data' LIKE mydb.mytable.
INSERT INTO mydb.mytable_new SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable;
DROP TABLE mydb.mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable_new RENAME mydb.mytable;
```

If you are concerned with indexes in RAM, just tune the InnoDB Buffer Pool size.

Give it a Try !!!